# Manual AWS X-Ray traces not showing even though they are sent

Tags: aws-xray

I'm sending xray information from Python manually (no Django, Flask, etc.). I can see the xray information sent in the logs, for example:

```
Jan 24 16:50:17 ip-172-16-7-143 python3[10700]: DEBUG:sending: {"format":"json","version":1}
Jan 24 16:50:17 ip-172-16-7-143 python3[10700]: {"aws": {"xray": {"sdk": "X-Ray for Python", "sdk_version": "2.4.3"}}, "end_time": 1579884617.5194468, "id": "c59efdf40abecd22", "in_progress": false, "name": "handle request", "service": {"runtime": "CPython", "runtime_version": "3.6.9"}, "start_time": 1579884515.5117097, "trace_id": "1-5e2b1fe3-c1c3cbc802cae49e9c364371"} to 127.0.0.1:2000.
```

But nothing shows up in the console. I've tried all the different filters and time frames, but nothing shows up. Where should I be looking?

**UPDATE:**
Adding xray logs:

```
2020-01-24T01:50:35Z [Info] Initializing AWS X-Ray daemon 3.2.0
2020-01-24T01:50:35Z [Info] Using buffer memory limit of 9 MB
2020-01-24T01:50:35Z [Info] 144 segment buffers allocated
2020-01-24T01:50:35Z [Info] Using region: us-east-2
2020-01-24T01:50:35Z [Info] HTTP Proxy server using X-Ray Endpoint : https://xray.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
2020-01-24T01:50:35Z [Info] Starting proxy http server on 127.0.0.1:2000
```

Comment: Are you running the xray daemon? Do you see any errors in daemon logs?

Comment: Yeah I'm running it, no errors

Comment: The daemon logs will show if traces are being sent. Can you post the log information here? I'm betting it's a misconfiguration between the SDK and daemon.

Comment: @AWSSandra added logs

Answer (score 2):

From the log it looks like your X-Ray daemon never received any trace segment, otherwise there should be a log line like "[Info] Successfully sent batch of 1 segments (0.100 seconds)".

Are you using the official X-Ray Python SDK? How did the "manually sending" work? Please verify the daemon and your application is running in the same network circumstance. For example, if the daemon is running in a container, please make sure its UDP 2000 port is opened, vice versa.